# redash configured behind nginx conf file with server location is duplicating the url path

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, redash

My nginx conf file entry for redash

```
location /redash/ {
    sub_filter ="/" ="/redash/";
    sub_filter ="/static/ ="/redash/static/;
    sub_filter ="/ldap/ ="/redash/ldap/;
    sub_filter ="/saml/login ="/redash/saml/login;
    sub_filter url(/static url(/redash/static;
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter_types application/javascript text/css text/xml text/javascript application/json text/plain;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /redash;

    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000;
}
```

This work for the server but when i refresh my page. On first access, i see url like this http://localhost/redash/

but on sub-sequent refresh redash gets appended, After multiple refresh, url looks like below.

http://localhost/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/redash/

Is there anything wrong with my redash configuration?